# Can't get WebRTC to work in different networks

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, webrtc, screensharing

I am trying to transfer a video streaming from one browser to another with WebRTC and socket.io. It works just fine in the same network. No image is getting through across different ones.

I use socket-io as a signal server. I register two browsers in a "room" and then start sending signals.

The code which is executed in the browser from which the streaming is sent:

```
function joinRoom(room) {
  if (room === '') {
    alert('Please type a room ID')
  } else {
        data = { room: room};
        socket.emit('join', data);
  }
}

// SOCKET EVENT CALLBACKS =====================================================
socket.on('room_created', async () => {
  console.log('Socket event callback: room_created')

  await setLocalStream(mediaConstraints)
  socket.emit('startc', {room: roomId, clientip: clientip})
  isRoomCreator = true
})


socket.on('full_room', () => {
  console.log('Socket event callback: full_room')

  alert('The room is full, please try another one')
})

socket.on('startc', async () => {
  console.log('Socket event callback: start_call')

  if (isRoomCreator) {
    rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers)
    addLocalTracks(rtcPeerConnection)
    rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = setRemoteStream
    rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = sendIceCandidate
    await createOffer(rtcPeerConnection)
  }
})

socket.on('offer', async (event) => {
  console.log('Socket event callback: offer')

  if (!isRoomCreator) {
    rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers)
    addLocalTracks(rtcPeerConnection)
    rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = setRemoteStream
    rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = sendIceCandidate
    rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event))
    await createAnswer(rtcPeerConnection)
  }
})

socket.on('answer', (event) => {
  console.log('answer');
  console.log('Socket event callback: webrtc_answer')

  rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event))
})

socket.on('webrtc_ice_candidate', (event) => {
  console.log('Socket event callback: webrtc_ice_candidate')

  // ICE candidate configuration.
  var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
    sdpMLineIndex: event.label,
    candidate: event.candidate,
  })
  rtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate)
})
```

The code that accepts the streamed media (vuejs):

```
    socket.on("offer", (data) => {
      this.$emit("closeWaitingToConnect");
      this.createAnswer(data);
    });

   joinMeToRoom() {
        console.log("joinToRoom: ", this.room);
        this.$socket.emit("join", this.room);

    }, //joinMeToRoom ()

createAnswer: function(event) {

      var roomId = this.room.room;
      let sessionDescription

      this.peer.ontrack = this.setRemoteStream
      this.peer.onicecandidate = this.sendIceCandidate
      this.peer.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event))

      try {
        sessionDescription = this.peer.createAnswer().then((answer) => {
          var anwer =
          console.log('sessionDescription');
          console.log(answer);
          this.$socket.emit('answer', {
            type: 'webrtc_answer',
            sdp: answer,
            sessionDescription: JSON.stringify(answer),
            roomId,
          })
          return this.peer.setLocalDescription(answer)
        });

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('cae: '+error)
      }
    },

    getScreenPosition() {
      const right = this.$refs.screen.getBoundingClientRect().right;
      const bottom = this.$refs.screen.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      return { bottom: bottom, right: right };
    },

    setRemoteStream(event) {
      console.log('event setRemoteStream');
      console.log(event);
      var stream_screen = document.querySelector("video");
      stream_screen.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      stream_screen.play();
      var remoteStream = event.stream
    },
```

I have setup my own TURN server and tried paid versions. Still can't get the stream across different networks.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the host secure? I'm no expert here but I made a video chat page and it worked great on a local network, but when I put it online I found out an `https` connection is required. I ended up using a LetsEncrypt cert on my server and it worked.

Comment: Thanks. It is secure on both sides